# Craftsman Opener will not close in hot weather except by holding down wired wall button

Tags: remote-control

During certain hours of day when sun is directly on garage door (and sensors?), the door OPENS fine from the remote or the wired wall button, but will only CLOSE by holding wired wall button down until door reaches closed position. (Remote does NOT work during these direct-sun hours.)  The malfunction that occurs when using remote during the direct-sun hours is the door starts to close (about one foot) then the lights on the main unit flash a few times, and this problem persists with the door then opening next time remote is pushed and lights blinking, then same problem starts again.  I have tried shielding the sensors (transmitter and receiver) from the sun, but the problem persists.  Once the sun is off the door, everything works fine (i.e., the remote and the wall button).  Opener works fine all winter, even if sun is on door.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the hot sun expands metal in the door structure and creates friction great enough to make the opener sense that friction as an obstruction.  It then reverses the door.  The normal override is to hold the button down.

When the door cools down and the metal shrinks the problem does not manifest itself.

When the door will not close properly, disconnect the carrier from the opener, ( pull the rope down) and open and close the door manually.  Perhaps have someone assist you. Look and listen for areas where things rub.  Once the issue is found make the adjustments needed or lubricate the dry parts.

Comment: Or possibly the heat causes the rails to which the eyes are attached to deflect (twist), causing them to come out of alignment.

Comment: After locating and reviewing the Craftsman manual online (troubleshooting section), and determining my "Learn" light was blinking 4 times and light on the opener was blinking 10 times following malfunction, I followed their advice and removed and cleaned the sensors (which had appeared to be steady and lined up).  This worked and door is now operating normally, even in hot weather.

Comment: @Betty,  Thanks for getting us the solution.